# How to make a non-JSONP cross-domain Ajax call in IE9 and earlier

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, cors

I want to call the following web service

```
var url = 'search.php',
    data = {
        addressdetails: 1,
        format: 'json',
        osmtype: 'node',
        q: 'london'
    };

$.ajax('//open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/' + url, {
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        var results = [];
        if (status === 'success' && !data.error) {
            console.log('success');
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

I created a JSFiddle with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JX27m/1

I've been told that IE8+ supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), so there should be a way to tweak this code to make it work on IE9, right?

Cheers,
Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) and you will see IE 8 & 9 have partial support. My guess is because CORS was not actually introduced as CORS in the specification till 2009 (after IE 8 & too late to appear in IE 9). They probably implemented support of [Access Control for Cross-Site Requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/) That eventually became CORS. They seem to support the [XDomainRequest Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx) for cross domain requests. Check the Can I Use resources tab to find some other articles.

Comment: I expect the main reason caniuse says "partial support" is the reason they actually give: *"Supported somewhat in IE8 and IE9 using the XDomainRequest object (but has limitations)"*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server in question supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and allows your origin, you can use IE's [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. jQuery doesn't do that for you because the jQuery team feel there are too many problems with the XDR object (details in [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283), near the bottom), but you can do it yourself, or there are plugins for jQuery that provide that functionality. For instance, [this one](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js) is linked from that same jQuery ticket.